# Connect and import data from SQL server

Tags: python, sql

I'm looking for importing data from my server. The connexion looks good but I couldn't execute it!
the message bellow appear:

> Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM 311_WQR_126.AI_StsPV':
> ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
> Server]Incorrect syntax near '311'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

This is my code :

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=**.**.***.*;'
                  'Database=Mydata;'
                  'UID=myUser;'
                  'PWD=myPW;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM 311_FCY_129.PID_StsSP')
```

Comment: Do you have a shema starting with numbers?

Comment: Schemas starting with other as characters shoundn't be used. I suggest to rename it

Answer (score 1):

Try adding square brackets to the schema name and table name.

SELECT * FROM [311_FCY_129].[PID_StsSP]

Answer (score 0):

This can be a problem due to the schema starting with numbers. Try using double quotes:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM "311_FCY_129".PID_StsSP')
```